# Determine difference between python objects

Tags: python, equality

Suppose I have:

```
tup1 = ((100,), (100,))
tup2 = tuple(map(tuple, np.array([100, 100]).reshape(-1,1)))
```

Now `tup1 == tup2` returns `True` (which I realize comes from structural equality).

However, as part of some python project I'm trying to do the following:

```
from comtypes.automation import (byref, windll, 
    POINTER, VARIANT, PyDLL, py_object, wintypes)

_dll = PyDLL(pythoncom.__file__) 
_pack = _dll.PyCom_VariantFromPyObject
_pack.argtypes = py_object, POINTER(VARIANT) 
_pack.restype = wintypes.BOOL
```

Now

```
_pack(tup1, VARIANT())
```

works while

```
_pack(tup2, VARIANT())
```

throws an exception. In what ways do `tup1` and `tup2` actually differ (apart from pointing to different addresses in memory) that can cause this

Comment: what exception is thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each type of object can define equality in their own terms. Tuples are equal when they have the same length and their *contents* are tested as equal. The contents test equal because both are also tuples that each test equal when paired up.

But while the integer values *in* the nested tuples test equal, they are *not the same type*. Integers test equality on numeric value, so `1 == 1.0` also is true, even though one object is an integer, the other a float. In the same vein, `tup1[0][0] == tup2[0][0]` is true because both sides have the same numeric value of 100.

And while the first tuple has Python `int` objects, your second tuple does not. Instead, you have a *`numpy` specific integer type* here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> tup2 = tuple(map(tuple, np.array([100, 100]).reshape(-1,1)))
>>> tup2[0][0]
100
>>> type(tup2[0][0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

This is hard to see as the representation for the value looks exactly the same as for a Python `int` type, but for that specific C API call you are making, `numpy.int64` is not recognised as an acceptable type.

You'd need to convert those `int64` objects back to standard Python integers:

```
>>> int(tup2[0][0])
100
>>> type(int(tup2[0][0]))
<class 'int'>
```

You can actually tell the numpy array to do this for you if you use [`array.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
>>> np.array([100, 100]).reshape(-1,1).tolist()
[[100], [100]]
>>> type(np.array([100, 100]).reshape(-1,1).tolist()[0][0])
<class 'int'>
```

From the `array.tolist()` documentation:

> Return a copy of the array data as a (nested) Python list. **Data items are converted to the nearest compatible Python type.**

(bold emphasis mine).

Create your tuples from there:

```
tup2 = tuple(map(tuple, np.array([100, 100]).reshape(-1,1).tolist()))
```

While `.tolist()` gives you a (nested) list structure of Python type equivalents, you can also get individual values with the [`numpy.item()` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html#numpy.ndarray.item), should you need to have efficient access to such values from an existing array.

Answer (score 1):

`tup1 == tup2` may be true, but the types are not identical. Try the following and convince yourself:

```
[[type(dt) for dt in t] for t in tup1]
```

and

```
[[type(dt) for dt in t] for t in tup2]
```